# Number of minutes in a time range - EXCEL

Tags: excel

I have a sheet for tracking my hours at work. We also have a time period between the hours of 07:30 & 18:00 where we can accrue 'flex time'. I want to know from my in and out times, how many hours:minutes I have made in flex.
Please can someone help with the calculation?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried subtracting one ftom the other?

Comment: Sorry perhaps it wasn't so clear, I need to know how many of my in and out time is between 07:30 and 18:00

Answer (score 1):

Fixed my formula to get correct answers. Bit odd but works now!

```
=C4+IF(A4-TIME(7,30,0)<0,A4-TIME(7,30,0),0)-IF(B4-TIME(18,0,0)>0,B4-TIME(18,0,0),0)
```

We take the total time then

if our time starts earlier than flex time starts, we ADD the difference between our start time and flex time, which of course will be a negative number

if our end time ends later than flex time ends, we SUBTRACT the difference between our end time and flex time

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of doing these is to use the *overlap formula* for two intervals

```
=max(0,min(end1,end2)-max(start1,start2))
```

So in your case it would be

```
=MAX(0,MIN(C2,TIMEVALUE("18:00"))-MAX(B2,TIMEVALUE("7:30")))
```

If some of your time cells contain strings instead of numbers you would need to check for these. One way of doing it is

```
=IFERROR(MAX(0,MIN(C2+0,TIMEVALUE("18:00"))-MAX(B2+0,TIMEVALUE("7:30"))),0)
```

[image]

If you ever did a night shift including midnight the formula would need further modification.

Comment: you always have the proper formula....eventually I will know them all to! I fixed my answer however and think that it does less computations!

Comment: Not always! But I think both solutions are fine.